# What is the best number of threads for my task? Task or ThreadPool?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I should parse some files from directory. And I would like to do it with different threads on machine, which have more than 1 core. For example, on machine with 4 core/cpu, 3 equal files will be parsed for time that takes parsing 1 this file.
What is the best number of threads? Should it be equal number of cpu.
What is more appropriate for this task: System.Threading.Tasks.Task or ThreadPool?
Thanks

Comment: What is involved in this "parsing"? Do you have complex computations? Or is it simply a matter of converting some format (e.g. text) to some other format (e.g. in-memory data structures)? If the latter, then the bottleneck is likely to be the disk and you're unlikely to get any performance benefit beyond two concurrent operations (and even that is iffy...two different threads competing for the same disk could actually slow things down).

Comment: Try different number of threads, time them, and determine what number works best. There isn't a "fixed" number we can suggest. It depends heavily on your environment and the CPU load.

Comment: It really depends on what you're doing. If parsing is mainly reading a large file from disk, then threads wont be of help here, you can revert to async IO. If most of the process is doing CPU bound work, benchmark your code to see which number of threads gives you optimal performance gains.

Comment: I just should convert format of data without complex computations and write it in new file. I'm going to make class, which will be analyse and convert each row of file and immediately write/append it in new file. And i'm going to run it like one thread - one file